# Keep connection alive with php

Tags: php, mysql

If i send request to server to - mysql_connect, select_db it replies in 250ms or so, after that everytime i send same request reply averages about 50ms. If i go idle for 10 seconds or more it goes back to 250ms reply

```
$user="";
$password="";
$database="";
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database " . $database);
```

Is there something i can do that everytime i send this request it doesnt go back to 250ms even if user goes idle for a bit.

I know for some people 200ms difference is silly but i really need this for my case.

Comment: Where is the database located, on the same server?

Comment: @Pekka yes on the same server